# Using XSLT to remove duplicate entires in a simple XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I am new to XSLT and am having a problem with removing duplicates from a simple XML file. Spent a lot of time trying to get it but it's never quite right. Here is the source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<language>
    <lang name="welcome">welcom</lang>
    <lang name="open">Open</lang>
    <lang name="close">Close</lang>
    <lang name="welcome">Welcome</lang>
    <lang name="copy">Copy</lang>
</language>
```

Desired output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<language>
    <lang name="open">Open</lang>
    <lang name="close">Close</lang>
    <lang name="welcome">Welcome</lang>
    <lang name="copy">Copy</lang>
</language>
```

The actual files are much larger than this and "lang" and "name" may change later in the file, and I only want to keep the last duplicate. Basically, if the tag and attributes are duplicated, only keep the last entry. I hope this is possible with XSLT 1.0. If not, I can always use multiple scripts in case lang does change to something else. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mention in your question about attributes. Can you have multiple attributes on your **lang** elements, or will it only ever be the **name** attribute?

Comment: There may be more attributes, but the tag and the name attribute are the only ones I need to compare. The other attributes, if any were to appear, would also be identical anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following XSLT should answer your question :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="lang[@name=following-sibling::lang/@name]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way, you filter every `lang` element that have a following sibling `lang` element with the same value for the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**A more general and much more efficient (linear) solution than the quadratical time complexity (O(N^2)) of the currently accepted answer. This is especially important in processing a large XML document, as the OP has told us the actual documents are**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLangByName" match="lang" use="@name"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "lang[not(generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kLangByName', @name)[last()]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<language>
    <lang name="welcome">welcom</lang>
    <lang name="open">Open</lang>
    <lang name="close">Close</lang>
    <lang name="welcome">Welcome</lang>
    <lang name="copy">Copy</lang>
</language>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<language>
   <lang name="open">Open</lang>
   <lang name="close">Close</lang>
   <lang name="welcome">Welcome</lang>
   <lang name="copy">Copy</lang>
</language>
```

**Explanation**:

Using the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Yes it was a large amount of data but not huge, and doesn't need to be run regularly. But I see what you mean, so thanks for the tip for future :)